# Как отключить прокрутку страницы, когда слайдер находится в начале или в конце, а параметр freeMode включён?

Tags: javascript, swiper

Я пытался решить проблему таким способом, но это не сработало:

```
let slider = new Swiper('.slider', {
  spaceBetween: 45,
  slidesPerView: 'auto',
  mousewheel: true,
  allowTouchMove: true,
  freeMode: true,
  scrollbar: {
    el: '.scroll',
    hide: false,
    draggable: true,
  },
  on: {
    scroll: function (swiper, event) {
      let scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
      let scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
      if (swiper.isBeginning || swiper.isEnd) {
        window.scrollTo(scrollLeft, scrollTop);
      }
    }
  }
});
```